# How can I see who is currently in a channel?

Tags: irssi

I can see this information when I initially connect, but is there a command I can run to see an updated list?

Comment: Did you look through the list of standard IRC commands?

Comment: There is tons of information here about irssi: http://www.irssi.org/documentation - Here's a good guide to get you started: http://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi

Answer (score 21):

Type

```
/names
```

in the whichever channel you want a list of users for. This is the [IRC command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands#NAMES) to do what you want.

Comment: ...or the shorter `/n` :)

Comment: @medigeek: I'm pretty sure that's just one of mIRCs (and possibly other clients) default aliases and not a standard IRC command.

Answer (score 2):

You can issue the command `who #channel`, which will list the users currently in the named channel.

Exactly how you'd do it and exactly how the output is displayed depends on the client; I'm not familiar with irssi so can't really comment on that.

For other IRC commands, see for example [technerd.net's summary of IRC commands](http://www.technerd.net/irc-commands.html). Note that many of those may very well be server-dependent.

Comment: if you are not familiar with IRSSI why answer!

Comment: @justintime Because I doubt that irssi does things differently enough to make the answer irrelevant or incomprehensible, as well as the fact that the only mention of irssi in the question is in the *tags*.